# InfoBright (MySQL) ERROR 5 (HY000): std::exception

Tags: mysql, infobright

I am doing a bulk upload to my InfoBright.

I have taken the data from server 1 into the outfile and trying to bulkupload to server 2. I copied data file generated by MySQL `OUTFILE` from server 1 to server 2. I changed the ownership of these data file on server 2 to mysql:mysql. The size of the file is 493 MB.

But when I try to execute following command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/fact1.data' INTO TABLE fact1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '''' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

I get following error:

```
ERROR 5 (HY000): std::exception
```

The error 5 says that mysql ran out of memory.

So, as a verification I took similar data present on the server 2 in one of the tables in `OUTFILE`. The size of this file is 503 MB.

And then used the following command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/localfact.data' INTO TABLE fact1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '''' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

This does work. Then why it is not working with the dump from server 1? What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in the previous versions of ICE.  There was a new release in December that resolves that issue. Please upgrade to 4.0.5 at [www.infobright.org](http://www.infobright.org)